# Xcode: Using a UIView transitionFromView moves the views up

Tags: animation, curl, view

I have the following animation to go between several pages:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.view 
                   toView:nextPage.view 
                   duration:0.5   
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                   completion: nil];
```

When the first view loads not a problem, but then when I press the button to goto the next page an so on, it seems as if the next page's view has jumped up, about 20 from the bottom, as if the status bar is removed, then when I go back to the first page the same happends here.

How can I prevent it from doing this.

i have tried the following

```
completion: ^(BOOL finished){nextPage.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
```

but still nothing.

Many Thanks si

Comment: I tried this on something else I am workign on that usign the NAvigation Controller, but I have created on a noraml viewbase project then hiddign it using the following code This went in my Delegate m file UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view]; then within my first view I hide it using [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]; anyway this some how removes my 20px gap at them btm not the right answer so if anyone can sugest  thanx

Comment: Write after looking at if with fresh eyes: When I put in the code `completion: ^(BOOL finished){nextPage.view.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)` as mentioned it did nothing so I thought for a while and as it goes up 20 I decided to try `CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460);` and this worked but it jumps down after the animation, so again thinking i placed `nextPage.view.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460);` just before `[UIView transitionFromView...` and well it seemed to solve my issue of the 20 gap appearing, this was on a test so will take to my project and report back soon.